# Python Kivy: hide virtual keyboard in Text Input Field

Tags: python, keyboard, hide, kivy, textinput

I am using the python kivy framework to develop a GUI which will then be most probably used on a desktop PC with (hardware) mouse and keyboard. My problem now is that when using the Text Input class, it automatically  creates a virtual keyboard if the Text Input field gets focused. 
Among other things I tried to set the option

```
keyboard_mode = 'managed'
```

implemented in my main the following way:

`textinputfield = TextInput(text="some initial text here", text_size=self.size, keyboard_mode='managed')`

which actually hides the keyboard but unfortunately also prevents the user from entering any data into the field.... I can't find any solution on google.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Yoav was close enough in his answer.

You need to set `keyboard_mode=system` in your kivy configuration, and not in the `TextInput`. If you always want to use the system keyboard, you can make this change in `~/.kivy/config.ini`.

Check [Kivy config](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/config.html) for more options, like setting this variable on a per-app basis etc.

Comment: perfect. that solved my problem. yes you are right, then Yoav was very close. I didn't know about that kivy config file. many thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
keyboard_mode = 'system'
```

It will use the **real** keyboard

Comment: keyboard_mode only allows options 'auto' or 'managed'. Are you sure about that?

Comment: I edited my post. you can check if the implementation is correct.